# scrapy isnt showing the arabic letters

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have spent the whole day looking for a way to display the Arabic letters with `scrapy` and nothing worked for me! I am scraping an Arabic website but i am not getting the right format of the arabic language.

here is what i am actually getting when i am saving the results in a csv file:

```
"Ø¨Ø·Ù„ Ù„ÙŠÙØ±Ø¨ÙˆÙ„ Ø§Ù„Ù‚Ø¯ÙŠÙ…" ÙŠØ±Ø¯ Ø¹Ù„Ù‰ Ø£Ù†ØµØ§Ø± "Ø§Ù„Ø±ÙŠØ¯Ø²"
```

here is my function:

```
def parse_details(self, response):
    vars = ArticlesItem()
    vars["title"] = response.css("h1.sna_content_heading::text").extract_first().strip()
    vars["article_summary"] = response.css("span.article-summary").extract_first().strip()
    vars["article_content"] = [i.strip() for i in response.css("div.article-body p::text").extract()]
    vars["tags"] = [i.strip() for i in response.css("div.article-tags h2.tags::text").extract()]
    yield vars
```

i tried to add `encode("utf-8")` but i am still not getting the right format

```
vars["title"] = ...extract_first().strip().encode("utf-8")
```

i am getting something like this:

```
b'\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb1\xd9\x82\xd9\x85 "\xd9\x85\xd8\xb0\xd9\x87'
      b'\xd9\x84".. \xd8\xa8\xd9\x86\xd8\xb2\xd9\x8a\xd9\x85\xd8\xa9 \xd9'
      b'\x8a\xd8\xaa\xd9\x81\xd9\x88\xd9\x82 \xd8\xb9\xd9\x84\xd9\x89'
      b' \xd9\x85\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb3\xd9\x8a \xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88'
      b'\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xaf\xd9\x88 \xd9\x88\xd8\xb5\xd9'
      b'\x84\xd8\xa7\xd8\xad'
```

Comment: Could you provide the corresponding URL?

Comment: Maybe the website isn't using utf8 encoding? If you could provide us with an url we could tell you more.

Comment: Dude, open that CSV in a text editor like Notepad or Notepad++ and it will show perfectly ... but if you open file in Microsoft Excel it will show incorrect data

Comment: I actually solved it by opening excel and load the data from the CSV file. I also had to choose UTF-8 from the list

Comment: zakaria, could you please provide a response to your question indicating how you solved your issue?

Comment: @Gallaecio sure,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I take the data you report in your question, and assign it to a variable, like this:

```
>>> a = (b'\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb1\xd9\x82\xd9\x85 "\xd9\x85\xd8\xb0\xd9\x87'
      b'\xd9\x84".. \xd8\xa8\xd9\x86\xd8\xb2\xd9\x8a\xd9\x85\xd8\xa9 \xd9'
      b'\x8a\xd8\xaa\xd9\x81\xd9\x88\xd9\x82 \xd8\xb9\xd9\x84\xd9\x89'
      b' \xd9\x85\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb3\xd9\x8a \xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88'
      b'\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xaf\xd9\x88 \xd9\x88\xd8\xb5\xd9'
      b'\x84\xd8\xa7\xd8\xad')
```

and I then decode these bytes on the (reasonable) assumption that they are UTF-8:

```
>>> a.decode()
'برقم "مذهل".. بنزيمة يتفوق على ميسي ورونالدو وصلاح'
```

it seems to me that you are getting back what you might be expecting, just not quite in the way you expect it.

Answer (score 1):

since `@gallaecio` wanted me to write an answer to my question

here is what i did:

1- open an empty excel sheet

2- go to data

3- choose From text/csv

4- under the file origin i had to change it from 1252 Western European(Windows) TO 65001 Unicode ( UTF-8 ), now i can read the arabic text !

5- Load !